# Once click the button the content of the textarea should be display to another div or textarea. and first textarea should be clear after clicking.

Tags: javascript

It is like Article Publishing People Can Publish their Articles. Once they are click the button it has to shown below .but in that textarea or div dont want text editing capabilities. once click the button it has to show below again they can post (Multiple).

```js
//<![CDATA[
        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
  //]]>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function doMagic() {

        var homeTown = document.getElementById("hometown").value;
        document.getElementById("comment").value = homeTown;


    }
```

```html
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
<textarea name="area2" id="hometown" style="width: 100%;">
       Some Initial Content was in this textarea
</textarea>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="publish" onClick="doMagic();" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;"></input>


 <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-12">
 <textarea  id="comment" style="background-color:#000;"></textarea>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
function doMagic() {
      var homeTown = document.getElementById("hometown").value;
      var ed = nicEditors.findEditor('comment')
      ed.setContent(homeTown);
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
<textarea name="area2" id="hometown" style="width: 100%;">
       Some Initial Content was in this textarea
</textarea>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="publish" onClick="doMagic();" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;"></input>


 <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-12">
 <textarea  id="comment"></textarea>
  </div>
 </div>
```

From NiceEdit's [documentation](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/521/Javascript%20API), it's quite clear that to set values in text areas that already have been initialized with niceedit, you need to use the OOTB functions. So instead of using vanilla JS, use

```
var ed = nicEditors.findEditor('comment');
ed.setContent(homeTown);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to display only in that textarea ? It seems that plugin converts all the textarea in that page to editors.

If you want you can simply display on the div itself.

```
//<![CDATA[
        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
  //]]>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function doMagic() {

        var homeTown = document.getElementById("hometown").value;
        document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = homeTown;


    }
```

And give the id to the div.

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
<textarea name="area2" id="hometown" style="width: 100%;">
       Some Initial Content was in this textarea
</textarea>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="publish" onClick="doMagic();" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;"></input>


 <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-12" id="comment">

  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. it is working but First Textarea Has to convert PageEditor.

Comment: @sinoob I dont understand what do you mean by `First Textarea Has to convert PageEditor.` ?

Comment: Textarea is not convetred to Editor. People can edit the text like bold ,italic